# Automatically proxy AJAX requests in both development and production environments

Tags: ajax, webpack, http-proxy, next.js

I am using `Next.js` and `Axios` libraries.

My axios requests look like this:

```
axios.get('/api/users/1')
```

This worked while I had API and rendering server inside same instance. 
But now my API backend is fully separated.

While in dev mode, it is hosted at `localhost:3001` while frontend (next) dev server is hosted on `localhost:3000`. In production rendering server is hosted at `https://example.com` while API is hosted at `https://api.someoherdomain.com`.

How to keep axios requests clean (without importing stuff and prefixing url string by hand), keeping them like `/api/users/1` but automactially making them `localhost:3000/api/users/1` while running development mode and `https://example.com/api/users/1` while hosted in production.

I need something like https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-custom-reverse-proxy but to work on both production and development mode.

> Not a recommended approach to production scale (hence
>   explicit dev flag) as we should scope proxy as outside UI applications
>   and have separate web server taking care of that.

If this is not possible, I am looking for the most elegant way to handle this. Any suggestions?

In production we use Plesk (which uses Ngnix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an `axios` instance and set the `baseUrl` parameter based on a environment variable :) 
Documentation here: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#creating-an-instance